# Exibir Log com comando TYPE

Tags: log, ms-dos

Estou utilizando o comando type para exibir um Log de registro de ponto na empresa, porem ele ñ mostra o conteúdo do log inteiro, apenas as ultimas linhas.

```
type C:\PASTA\LOG-TESTE.log 

@echo off
pause
```

- O parametro | MORE no comando type não funciona para mim pois o usuário teria que descer a página utilizando o teclado até a ultima linha.
- Exibir o Log com bloco de notas usando o comando 'start' não serviria pois o usuário teria que descer a barra de rolagem até a ultima linha para visualizar os mais recentes.

Alguma solução?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quanto a aparecer no final do arquivo não há o que fazer, pois o `type` lista e vai adicionando no *buffer* da tela e para no final. Se quiser ver o arquivo todo tem que rolar a barra até o início.

Já quanto ao tamanho do arquivo, se esse for muito grande realmente o *buffer* não vai suportar e vai "cortar" o conteúdo. Nesse caso, você pode mudar o *buffer* e o tamanho da tela pra comportar tudo o conteúdo do arquivo usando o comando `mode`.

O comando `mode` permite, entre outras coias, mudar a quantidade de linhas/colunas, com isso deve resolver o seu problema, por exemplo setando isso antes do type:

```
mode con:cols=120 lines=5000
```

Se o arquivo for maior, pode aumentar as colunas e as linhas, até atender sua necessidade

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela ajuda!